# Select multiple meta values with $wpdb->get_result

Tags: sql, wordpress

I'm trying to put together a google map for wordpress posts, which have a lat and long saved as meta values.

I need the lat and long output as two separate values in a list such that I could call them with result[1] and result[2]. Right now I can output both lat and long but they're as separate entries on a list ( i.e. each post title will be listed twice, once for lat and once for long, I need it to be listed once with lat and long as two of it's values)

Here's how the code's looking now (the printf is just to test the output of $result):

```html
  <?php
$lat = 'latitude';
$long = 'longitude';
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "
        SELECT 
            post_title, 
        meta_value
        FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} 
        ON ( $wpdb->posts.ID = {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id )
        WHERE meta_key = '$lat'
        OR meta_key = '$long'
    " );

    foreach( $results as $result )
    {
        printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', htmlspecialchars( var_export( $result, true ) ) );
    }

?>

<style type="text/css">
      html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #map { height: 350px; width:100%; }
    </style>
    
  <script type="text/javascript">



// MAP

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {lat: 53.343156, lng: -6.258545},
    scrollwheel: false
  });

  setMarkers(map);
}

// LOCATIONS

var locations = [
<?php

    foreach( $results as $result ) {

        echo "\t\t\t['"
             . str_replace("'", "\'", $result[0])
             . "', " . $result[1]
             . ", '" . $result[3] . "'"
             . "],\n";
    } ?>            ];


function setMarkers(map) {
  // Adds markers to the map.
  
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var result = results[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: result[1], lng: result[2]},
      map: map,
      title: result[0]
    });
  }
}
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyMapKey&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `get_post_meta()`?

Comment: Thanks for the response mevius. Would you mind clarifying how.

I see how I could add:

`$latitude = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'latitude', true );
$longitude = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'longitude', true );`

but then how could I call that from within:

`var locations = [
<?php

    foreach( $results as $result ) {

        echo "\t\t\t['"
             . str_replace("'", "\'", $result[0])
             . "', " . $result[1]
             . ", '" . $result[3] . "'"
             . "],\n";
    } ?>            ];`